# How to get first element with the given href faster

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I have working sample which produce the list of html elements with the given href. But I need only first one and speed is important, how to optimize this code?

```
import lxml.html
input = """<div class="post" style="height: 36px; ">
some div text 
<a href="http://site.com/" target="_blank">Look here</a>, 
some div text also </div>
"""
root = lxml.html.fromstring(input)
el = root.xpath("//*[@href='http://site.com/']")[0]
el.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an index in your xpath expression: `(//*[@href='http://site.com/'])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure it really is faster is to measure, measure, measure. The [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) can help.

Back to your problem, how about this?

```
text = root.xpath('//*[@href='http://site.com/'][1]/text()')
```